# handling page refresh and forward/backward function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

i am using react and next.js for making API request(from search bar) and displaying the list of movies on the homepage and every search result will take me to a different page,which will show data related to that movie.
Every time when i refresh the details page then the result of query is lost due to which wrong api request is made and search results are also lost when i use backwards/forward button.

**index.js**

```
  <Link href={`/Details?id=${movie.imdbID}`}>  //code to take me to the Details page
```

**Details.js**

```
const Details =()=>{    
const router = useRouter();
let [result,setResult]=useState({});
const query=router.query.id;  //storing the id from the URL

useEffect(() => {
axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?',
            {params:{
                apikey:'',
                i:query,
                plot:'full'
                }   
            }).then(response=> setResult(response.data))
         }, []);
    return <SearchBar />    
 } export default Details;
```

also i have implemented a Searchbar component used it in the index.js which works fine.i wish to use the same component in the details.js file to avoid code redundancy but i dont know the correct approach.

**index.js**

```
      <SearchBar whenSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit}/>
```

**SearchBar.js**

```
    onFormSubmit=(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.whenSubmit(this.state.term);
    }

    render(){
    <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
           <input type="text" value={this.state.term} placeholder="search any movie" 
            onChange={event=>this.setState({term: event.target.value})} />
      </form>}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs, you'll find that:

> Note: Pages that are statically optimized by automatic static optimization will be hydrated without their route parameters provided (query will be empty, i.e. {}). After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the query object. If your application cannot tolerate this behavior, you can opt-out of static optimization by capturing the query parameter in getInitialProps.

So, the solution is to add `getInitialProps` to your component:

```
Details.getInitialProps = async () => ({});

export default Details;
```

Or change `useEffect` to fetch data only when `id` is available:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {
      axios
        .get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?", {
          params: {
            apikey: "",
            i: query,
            plot: "full"
          }
        })
        .then(response => setResult(response.data));
    }
  }, [query]);
```

Comment: thanks second solution works,the search result are gone when i go back to previous page ,do i need caching to store the results?

Comment: @nitishy2j to preserve state between client-side navigation, extend `next/app` (which is a top-level component that never gets unmounted) and place your sate there: https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-app

Answer (score 0):

As i can observe your code you are using query param which will lost your querystring value every reload or can say backward and forward. you can try path_param instead of query_param.

1. `<Route path="/Details/:id" component={MovieDetailsComponent} exact></Route>`
2. `<Link to={`/movies/${id}`}>`
3. movies details page `parseInt(props.match.params.id);`

i used this approach to fetch data from server in useEffect and it's working fine for me you can try also.

Comment: Actually for my project i have to use next.js and next.js has got its own way of route handling.

Comment: oh that's problem